# Find $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{t \in [n, +\infty)}[t,t^2]$ and $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{t \in [n, +\infty)}[t,t^2]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to find
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{t \in [n, +\infty)}[t,t^2]$$
and
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{t \in [n, +\infty)}[t,t^2]$$
My attempt. For the first one, we notice
$$\bigcap_{t \in [n, +\infty)}[t,t^2] = [n,n^2] \cap [a_1,a_1^2] \cap [a_2,a_2^2] \cap \dots$$
At the same time
$$[n,n^2] \cap [n^2+1,(n^2+1)^2] = \emptyset$$
This means
$$\bigcap_{t \in [n, +\infty)}[t,t^2] = \emptyset$$
and
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{t \in [n, +\infty)}[t,t^2]=\emptyset$$
For the second one
$$\bigcup_{t \in [n, +\infty)}[t,t^2] = [n,n^2] \cup [a_1,a_1^2] \cup [a_2,a_2^2] \cup \dots = [n, +\infty)$$
Now, we have
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} [n, +\infty)= [1, +\infty) \cap [2, +\infty) \cap [3, +\infty) \cap \dots$$

Does this mean $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{t \in [n, +\infty)}[t,t^2] = \emptyset$?

Comment: To me, everything is ok, but the last statement. It seems to me that if we consider $R$ with $\infty$, than it has in some sense a unique element $\infty$(even though none of these sets contains $\infty$).

Comment: And one more thing. To prove your first statement as it is said in the answer beneath, you should show that for every $n$ , $n+1 \in (n,n^{2})$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one, your result is correct, but your method is flawed.

You claim

> $$\bigcap_{t \in [n, +\infty)}[t,t^2] = [n,n^2] \cap [a_1,a_1^2] \cap [a_2,a_2^2] \cap \dots$$

But this is highly inacurate for two reasons:

1. You did not define what $a_i$ is.
2. The intersection is indexed with an **uncountable** set, so it's not accurate to write it down the way you did.

What you *can* claim is that if $x\in \bigcap_{t \in [n, +\infty)}[t,t^2]$, then, for every $t\in [n,\infty)$, $x$ must be an element of $[t,t^2]$.

This should be enough to show that the intersection is $\emptyset$, and from there, that the entire set is the empty set.

---

For the second, you made the same mistake with $a_i$ as in the first.

Also, you are rushing and are making claims without proof.

Your intuition is correct that $$\bigcup_{t\in [n, \infty)}[t,t^2] = [n,\infty),$$
but this is math. It isn't enough to just *think* that some equation must hold, you have to **prove** it does.

To prove the statement, you have to prove that the two sets are equal, and the easiest way to show this is to show that each is a subset of the other. In other words, show that

- If $x\in \bigcup_{t\in [n, \infty)}[t,t^2]$, then $x\in [n,\infty)$.
- If $x\in [n,\infty)$, then $x\in \bigcup_{t\in [n, \infty)}[t,t^2]$.

Again, note that $x\in \bigcup_{t\in [n, \infty)}[t,t^2]$ if and only if, for some $t\geq \infty$, $x$ is an element of $[t,t^2]$